The libc6 and libpam0g is half installed, and I can not reinstall
enter image description here
If I apt install --reinstall libc6 or dpkg -i libc6.deb, this will be a long time in unpacking and no progress.
enter image description here

Both links give me error that they can not load.

Please provide text rather than a picture of text; why are you trying to install outdated packages, ie. libpam0g | 1.5.3-5ubuntu5.1         | noble-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x is what I'd expect to see you installing.

This question is similar to: package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic is not ready for configuration cannot configure (current status `half-installed'). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
